# Interacting Phaser 3 with Dom

Tags: html, phaser-framework

I create a **canvas** field using **Phaser 3**. And this field is added to the end of the **body**. How can I add it to any **div**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the Phaser canvas in a specific `<div>` by adding an `id` to the `<div>` and referencing it as the `parent` in your Phaser game configuration.

```
<div id="gameContainer"></div>
```

```
config = {
  type: Phaser.CANVAS,
  ...
  parent: 'gameContainer'
};
```